# Merge PDFs with PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using PDFMerger to merge PDFs but when i attempt to call the file that merges the pdfs `merge.php` by using ajax i get a 500 internal server error.  When i type the file in the browser there is no 500 internal server error.

Here is the `merge.php` file.

```
$arr = $_REQUEST['idArray'];
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$i=0;
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $arr2[$i] = $value;
    $i++;
}

$filename = implode("-",$arr2);

$loop = 0;
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/'.$arr2[0].'.pdf', 'all');

foreach($arr2 as $values) {
    if($loop>0) {
        $pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/'.$arr2[1].'.pdf', 'all')
    }

    $loop++;
}
$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/'.$filename.'.pdf');
```

Here is the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
            url:"https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/mpdf/examples/merge.php", //page to merge PDFs
            data: { idArray : id_array },
            type:'POST',
            success:function() {

}
});
```

Why do i get a 500 internal server error when using ajax with this file?

How do i solve this?  I need to merge PDFs using ajax so i can print multiple PDFs at once.

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Yes at the top of my PHP file i have `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and no errors.

Comment: the file works but not with an ajax call?

Comment: I think your foreach loop will become an infinite loop.

Comment: What do you intend to do with your $loop variable. I think there might be a simpler way to implement what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Are you sure the request is getting passed to your merge.php file? Try var_dump($arr) and see what you get.

Comment: I'm using PDF Merger `https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/` the $loop variable is just to determine the 1st,2nd,3rd,4th pdf files etc

Comment: Try changing         $pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/'.$arr2[1].'.pdf', 'all') to         $pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/'.$arr2[$loop].'.pdf', 'all')

Comment: tried both of those suggestions. i check chrome development tools and the query string parameters are `idArray[]:12562`,`idArray[]:12561` but still 500 internal server error?

Comment: Can you post the error detail form the server? you can use chrome's dev tools and see `network` tab, click on your ajax call which return 500, if you have turned on all error, you should still see some error text when 500 . and you can install `xdebug` to see more error info.

Comment: I've checked the network tab only error code i see is `Status Code:500 Internal Server Error` and no response data.

Comment: Simplify the PHP right down to a simple response, then progressively build it back up and see when it breaks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue; was anyone able to resolve this issue?